# bash print 10 odd numbers then 10 even numbers

Tags: bash

How can I print 10 odd numbers and then the 10 even numbers then the next 10 odd numbers then the next 10 even numbers and so on.
Something like this:

1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20

21
23
25
27
29
31
33
35
37
39
22
24
26
28
30
32
34
36
38
40
...

I know how to print each apart but combined I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Please provide some code that you are starting with, so we can assist.

Comment: Where should the sequence end? Are you just looking to print the values, or do you want to loop through them, or what?

Comment: This sounds like homework and is rather easy to do with a few google searches. There is an operator called the `modulus` (%) I would recommend looking into as a hint.

Comment: it's not homework, the sequence should end somewhere arround 4000 I would prefer a loop.

Comment: I have a list of ports and want to start them this way, first 10 odd then 10 even and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example:

```
echo {1..19..2}; echo {2..20..2}; echo {21..39..2}; echo {22..40..2}
```

In a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [ "$i" -lt 4000 ]; do
    for j in $i $((i+1)); do
        printf '%s ' $( seq $j 2 $((j+18)) ); echo
    done
    i=$((i+20))
done
```

Comment: something like this but with a loop

Comment: @usersubuser Loop added.